# Connecting time at JFK from terminal 5 to terminal 4

Tags: international-travel

Arriving from MCO/Orlando on Jet Blue at 8:40AM Thursday October 26, 2017. Connecting to Emirates Airline in route to BKK/Bankok departing at 11:20AM same day. Separate tickets. Is this workable?

Comment: That may be cutting it close because it really depends on how busy the airport is at that time of day. I assume you will need to pick up your baggage from Jet Blue and recheck at Emirates then go through TSA. Baggage claim may take 20 minutes then getting over to Emirates for check in. Depending on how busy that time period is, it could take 30 minutes or longer to get through TSA.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Terminal Service in JFK. I believe you will not spend more than 1 hour. So, you should have enough time.

https://www.airport-jfk.com/terminals.php